# Laravel 6.x, I'm trying change to the URL home to custom own URL. Because I'm building auth default login and registration

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

When I log-in the page it will redirect to the home page but I need and replace home to custom URL.also custom URL according to **web.php** file.

In **web.php** file

```
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('index/sign',function (){
    return view('login-page');
})->name('login-page');

Route::middleware(['auth','admin'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('index/admin',function (){
        return view('admin');
    });
    Route::get('index/student',function (){
        return view('student');
    });
    Route::get('index/staff',function (){
        return view('staff');
    });
});
```

In **RouteServiceProvider.php** file
`public const HOME = '/home';`
In **RegisterController.php** file
`protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;`
In **LoginController.php** file

````
protected function redirectTo()
    {
        if ((Auth::user())->user_role == 'admin')
        {
            return 'admin';
        }
        elseif ((Auth::user())->user_role == 'staff')
        {
            return 'staff';
        }
        elseif ((Auth::user())->user_role == 'student')
        {
            return 'student';
        }
        else
        {
            return redirect('sign');
        }
    }```
````

Comment: Your `redirectTo()` needs to return a valid URL e.g `return url('index/student')` nothing of what you are returning is actually valid

Comment: When I have opened the login-page according to route('login-page') Then It will not open the admin page according to the route but It will open login or home page. Actually I need to open the admin/staff/student page. If the home page opened and I want to replace the home page to admin or someone else.

Answer (score 0):

@apokryfos comment taken into account, using named routes you could do something like this

```
Route::middleware(['auth','admin'])->group(function () {
  Route::get('index/admin',function (){
    return view('admin');
  })->name('admin');
  Route::get('index/student',function (){
    return view('student');
  })->name('student');
  Route::get('index/staff',function (){
    return view('staff');
  })->name('staff');
});
```

and then you redirectTo method could look like this

````
protected function redirectTo()
{
    if ((Auth::user())->user_role == 'admin')
    {
        return route('admin');
    }
    elseif ((Auth::user())->user_role == 'staff')
    {
        return route('staff');
    }
    elseif ((Auth::user())->user_role == 'student')
    {
        return route('student');
    }
    else
    {
        return redirect('sign');
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

@apokryfos , @edwin-krause

When I have opened the **login-page** according to route('login-page') Then It will not open the **admin** page according to the route but It will open **login** or **home** page. Actually I need to open the **admin/staff/student** page. If the **home** page opened and I want to replace the **home** page to **admin** or someone else.